Is possible to programatically create an IAM Identity Center instance from an AWS Organization management account?
It is necessary to create/enable an IAM Identity Center instance from the an AWS Organization management account to fully enable the Identity Center features, as documented here. However, the SDK for the CreateInstanceCommand states:

The CreateInstance request is rejected if the following apply:

The instance is created within the organization management account.

An instance already exists in the same account.



This seems to say it isn't possible to do the recommended and necessary thing, yeah? I have confirmed that this is the case:
const ssoAdminClient = new SSOAdminClient({ 
  credentials : organizationManagementAccountCredentials, 
  region      : instanceRegion
})
const createInstanceCommand = new CreateInstanceCommand({ Name : instanceName })
const createInstanceResults = await ssoAdminClient.send(createInstanceCommand) // throws

Results in:
ValidationException: Organization management account is not allowed to perform the operation.

This seems to be completely at odds with the recommendation and makes it impossible (?) to create a fully functional Identity Center. Or am I missing something?

I get the same error message when using the official AWS CLI:
$ aws sso-admin create-instance

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateInstance operation: Organization management account is not allowed to perform the operation. (Service: SsoInstancePublic, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6c0bdc2d-18af-4839-8675-65563be683c8)

